# refactor folder "layout" to "layout-sw600dp" and it cannot work

Tags: android-layout

Before this, I make an application using the settings for normal phone and now I want to switch to using the tablet .When I refactor the folder "layout" to "layout-sw600dp", it cannot work in emulator. plz help me.tq